# Usage of the term "good egg"

Tags: idioms, dialects

I came across the informal idiom ***good egg*** which means ***a likeable or pleasant person***. The idiom seems somewhat old-fashioned.

My question is: How common is this idiom inside and outside the USA ? And which age group still uses it.

Comment: The post notice here is not a criticism of the question (I really really wish the bold sentence at the start wasn't there), but rather is intended to head off anecdotal answers.

Comment: What does "regional parts of the United States" mean? Do you just mean east/mid/west/south, or are you interested in more specific divisions, like local dialects or ethnic groups? Are you interested in a particular area? It's unlikely that there is precise usage information in the way you can get maps of [pop vs soda](https://www.businessinsider.com/soda-pop-coke-map-2018-10?r=US&IR=T) but it might be possible to pick characteristic sources from New York or Los Angeles and see if they use it.

Comment: Search terms "is a good egg,are a good egg" in Google Ngrams gives: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+a+good+egg%2C+is+a+good+egg.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20a%20good%20egg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20good%20egg%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20a%20good%20egg%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20good%20egg%20.%3B%2Cc0 As far as I can see, there is no hope of answering your question about the regions of the US as there seems to be no data, and thus answers will be opinions.

Comment: My impression is that it was fairly popular 40-50 years ago, but it's fallen out of use.  I would guess that a lot of 20-somethings do not know its meaning.

Comment: All l want to know which part of the USA              ( north,south,east,west) this idiom is used in.

Comment: It's not presently used (very much) in any part of the USA.

Comment: I live in upstate NY.  I just queried my 19yo son and his 16yo friend.  Son had heard it and told me what it meant but friend had never heard it before.  (Friend doesn't do homework or read books for fun.)

Comment: Whether someone has heard it probably depends on what movies/TV he watches. They'll hear it if they watch old shows or modern period pieces.

Comment: It's not common. Older speakers, and people who read a fair bit of 19th and 20th century literature, will have heard of "good egg". It belongs to the eras of Oscar Wilde and Noel Coward.